# Jquery pagination dependant on viewport size?

Tags: jquery, pagination, viewport

Is it possible to have jquery pagination that limits the amount of results per page depending on what size the viewport is?

One might require this if they were going for a one page app where all of the elements on the page were required to fit in the viewport..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that you know what the height of each result is, the following code should point you in the right direction:

```
var paginationHeight = ...
var windowHeight = $(window).height();
var numberOfResults = windowHeight / paginationHeight;
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if there is a jQuery plugin for this. But- You could calculate the number of pages that can be displayed based on the table height & the row height. This can be used for the pagination instead.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, try searching for something common on [this page](http://www.boatinfo.no/lib/bulletins.html) and resize the browsers height, the pagination pages will increase exponentially as the search results per page decrease, all done with jQuery.